# How to determine root cause for Communication link failure TCP Provider: The specified network name is no longer available?

Tags: sql-server-2008, networking, ssis, windows-server-2008, virtual-machine

Here is my latest effort at revising this question. But this time, I am trying to follow the good counsel given by Oded in his article [Getting good answers on StackOverflow](http://odedcoster.com/blog/2010/07/28/getting-good-answers-on-stackoverflow-part-1-of-n/).

I need to find out how I can determine the root cause for the following error:

> Communication link failure
>
> TCP Provider: The specified network name is no longer available

From time to time, I am seeing this error when running a set of SSIS packages. This error can occur when one to many packages are run from:

1. A SQL Server Agent Job
2. A batch file
3. In debug mode from BIDS

The full error message I see is as follows:

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>       An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Communication link failure".
>       An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "TCP Provider: The specified network name is no longer available.
>       ".
>
> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>       An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0" Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Protocol error in TDS stream".
>       An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0" Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Communication link failure".
>       An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0" Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

This is an overview of how I have designed the ETL process:

- Two servers
- Both are virtual machines
- The SSIS packages run on an application server
- The SQL Server database lives on a database server

I use an OLE DB connection manager to connect from the SSIS package on the application server to the SQL Server database on the database server.

The packages run as a file system deployment on the application server and not as a database deployment on the database server.

The main reason for this is that the ETL is integrated with a set of tools no found on and drives not accessible to the database server. These tools include Apex Data Loader for Salesforce and pgAdmin III.

So far I cannot consistently reproduce this error. However, this is what I have observed:

- Failure occurs more frequently during regular business hours
- Failure occurs less frequently during off hours

For about a two hour period on a Friday morning I was able to successfully reproduce the error on a specific package.

The error occurred during a large data flow if a child package call that precedes the large data flow was enabled.

The error did not occur during the same large data flow if the child package call that precedes the large data flow was disabled.

The child package in question calls back to the database to retrieve a tiny amount of information for use in an email body and then sends the email.

It feels like maybe a resource limit is being exceeded?

Maybe a connection limit?

I am wondering what tools I should be using to try and determine the root cause of the error.

Technical details about the two servers involved are listed below:

> **SQL Server and Database Server info:**
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64)   Jun 17 2011 00:54:03   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)
>
> **SSIS info:**
>   Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Version 9.0.30729.1 SP
>   Microsoft .NET Framework Version 3.5 SP1
>
> **Application Server info:**
>   OS name: Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
>   Version: 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601

I have researched the error message online and found these, but would really like to get an expert's insight before proceeding:

- [How to Disable TCP Chimney, TCPIP Offload Engine (TOE) or TCP Segmentation Offload (TSO).](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH197934)
- [Using Netsh Commands to Enable or Disable TCP Chimney Offload](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg162682%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Further testing shows that this is not "an SSIS thing" as the same error is seen at the same rate when using SQL Server Management Studio. The complexity of the query does not make the error more or less likely. In an attempt to resolve, we have tried one fix (below):

- **[#1 How to Disable TCP Chimney, TCPIP Offload Engine (TOE) or TCP Segmentation Offload (TSO).](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH197934)**

This was our first attempt. TCP Chimney is now disabled on the Application Server and the Database Server. Testing shows that the same error occurs at the same rate.

So where to go from here? Honestly I am not sure. One seemingly good option remains:

- Application Server and Database Server SQL Server installations do not exactly match
- Application Server = SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64)
- Database Server = SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64)

The plan is to upgrade the SQL Server installation on the Application server. Its kind of a hit and hope, but at this point this seems like the best option. Something in my brain tells me that this might be solved by fixing a hardware issue (by that I mean a repair or a replace) and that there might not be anything that hardware and software configuration can do about it.

However, I am still not sure how to go about determining a root cause. I am still left wondering what tools I should be using to diagnose the root cause.

Comment: Did you get it sorted?

Comment: @matcheek thanks for the inquiry. Sorry to say, nope not yet...although I did try some stuff and break some stuff. You are welcome to learn from my fail. I have updated the question with current status.

Comment: @santiago_jon, I see this same error in my web server logs. Python code using ADO to talk with SQL 2008r2. Full stack is VMs, so it's not likely a hardware issue.

Comment: I have suffered and fixed this error before. If you're connecting to a named instance, try by changing the connection string to use the port number instead. Also, review if your VM or the host has any sort of load monitoring software, or DDOS protection software that might be disconnecting your session as "protection".

Comment: Before doing any other investigations, I would start by bringing both servers up to the latest SQL Service Pack available.  They are both several SPs behind WRT http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com.au/ Why would you keep using software with known, resolved bugs?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out @santiago_jon?

Comment: Do you specify a hostname for your SQL Server connections? If so, have you tried specifying an IP address instead? Also, as @CesarVega mentioned, if you don't specify the port number for SQL Server, you could try adding that, too.

Comment: Is it possible that you've used up all your TCP ports? You can run netstat /n to see if the list has almost all ports in use.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have AV software on Application Server side? If yes, try to disable AV - sometime AV blocks TCP/IP traffic. Issue with "The specified network name is no longer available" was solved by disabling AV here:
  https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/239423-the-specified-network-name-is-no-longer-available-while-writing-to-shared-dir

Comment: Onec it was the case. Our antivirus software isn't responding. Our dupport did something with it but I don't know what.

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that the connection was forcibly closed. You have also mentioned this occur when you run a lot of jobs. Chances are, the network firewall is to blame. You should reach out to the firewall administrator to research the logs in order to see if the firewall closed the connection. If this is the case then two potential solutions exist:

1. Add an exception to whatever firewall rule is being triggered and causing the connection to be closed.
2. Stop running so many jobs concurrently. You should consider running them in sequence. This also adheres to the idea of being a good network citizen.

Comment: Just got rid of it. It wasn't a production stand this time and a simple server restart was helpful. I've requested an investigation and will let know if they find anything. No need to run it in a sequence. That's good.

Answer (score 0):

1. First off did you tried to remove the large send offload setting on the nic ?
2. Second point, can you run a wireshark to capture the packets if you can reproduce the error ?
3. Third point, did you tried to change the vnic from the VM ? some model can cause issue. (If you use vmxnet3, try e1000, etc..)
4. Last point, does you have a vswitch between them, they are on same host, a physical switch between, etc... A badly configured switch can drop traffic, if inside the host the same host and same vswitch it's the best test, as the traffic never leave the server.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are multiple causes for this issue. For me it was the SQL file being too big at about 150MiB. Splitting it into smaller files worked for me.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to identify `SQL file` size is too large. What was the use case where you observed the error and what was the error message you observed.

Answer (score 0):

One possible root cause could be the active directory membership count as we experiencer recently. That will among other influence the size of Kerberos token that can influence the SQL server login steps as well.

Details:

- [The login packet is structurally invalid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-17832-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver16)
- [Kerberos Token Size](http://woshub.com/kerberos-token-size-and-issues-of-its-growth/)

Note: We observed error log entries on the SQL Server like:

> The login packet used to open the connection is structurally invalid; the connection has been closed. Please contact the vendor of the client library.'

On the client we observed the following error message:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

This issue was only affecting some AD users. There was no general service interruption.

Using the following command we determined the active directory membership:

```
PS> $groups = (az ad user get-member-groups --id {user identifier} |ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable)
PS> $groups.Count
294
```

Or we can also use the following command:

```
PS> $token = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
PS> $token.Groups.count
771
```

Connecting to the server with different providers yield different result:

Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server Version 17.07.0002:

```
Data Source Name: SOME_NAME
Data Source Description:
Server: SQLSERVER.DOMAIN.COM
Database: CORE_DATABASE
Language: (Default)
Data Encryption: Yes
Trust Server Certificate: Yes
Multiple Active Result Sets(MARS): No
Mirror Server: 
Translate Character Data: Yes
Log Long Running Queries: No
Log Driver Statistics: No
Use Regional Settings: No
Use ANSI Quoted Identifiers: Yes
Use ANSI Null, Paddings and Warnings: Yes
Authentication: ActiveDirectoryIntegrated
-----------

Running connectivity tests...

Attempting connection
Connection established
Verifying option settings
INFO: Connection was encrypted without server certificate validation.
Disconnecting from server

TESTS COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY!
```

Microsoft SQL Server Native Client Version 11.00.7462:

```
Data Source Name: SOME_NAME
Data Source Description: 
Server: SQLSERVER.DOMAIN.COM
Use Integrated Security: Yes
Database: (Default)
Language: (Default)
Data Encryption: No
Trust Server Certificate: No
Multiple Active Result Sets(MARS): No
Translate Character Data: Yes
Log Long Running Queries: No
Log Driver Statistics: No
Use Regional Settings: No
Use ANSI Quoted Identifiers: Yes
Use ANSI Null, Paddings and Warnings: Yes

-----------

Running connectivity tests...

Attempting connection
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]TCP Provider: The specified network name is no longer available.

[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Communication link failure

TESTS FAILED!
```

SQL Server - was not able to configure:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try using ODBC instead of OLE DB for your connection to the database.

Comment: How does this help in determining the root cause?

Comment: p1: This answer partially shows that the provider selection has some influence in the issue.